# How to access dataset from S3 bucket in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dataset, boto3

I have a Jupyter Notebook and I want to access a dataset that is in S3 bucket( it is publicaly accesible)

```
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='sagemaker-eu-central-1-261218592922' )
for content in response['Contents']:
    obj_dict = s3.get_object(Bucket='sagemaker-eu-central-1-261218592922', Key=content['Key'])
    print(obj_dict)
```

I am using a `boto3` client (s3). Ok so I go through the contents of the bucket with code above, but how does one access the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the contents of the file are, or what you want to do after, I can only offer a generic solution -

```
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='sagemaker-eu-central-1-261218592922' )
for content in response['Contents']:
    obj_dict = s3.get_object(Bucket='sagemaker-eu-central-1-261218592922', Key=content['Key'])
    contents = obj_dict['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

More details on this can be found at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object